# Java comparable interface compareTo(Object o), what is object o?

Tags: java, interface, comparable

Beginner, can't seem to wrap my head around this.

Item Class

```
public class Item implements Comparable {

private int number;
private String description;

public Item(int num, String descript){
    this.number = num;
    this.description = descript;
}

public int getNumber(){
    return number;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}

@Override public int compareTo(Object o){
    Item i = (Item) o;
    if(this.getNumber() < i.getNumber())
        return -1;

    if(this.getNumber() > i.getNumber())
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

}
```

Main method

```
Item[] items = new Item[3];
    items[0] = new Item(102, "Duct Tape");
    items[1] = new Item(103, "Bailing wire");
    items[2] = new Item(101, "Chewing Gum");

    Arrays.sort(items);

    for (Item i : items){
        System.out.println(i.getNumber() + ": " + i.getDescription());
    }
```

When the main method instantiate `items[0] = new Item(102, "Duct Tape");` Which goes through Item constructor to set current variable number, description.

My problem is I can't seem to understand what is being passed in the compareTo argument, therefore I can't seem to understand `this.getNumber() < i.getNumber()` is doing...

Return a negative number if current object is less than passed object?

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is I can't seem to understand what is being passed in the `compareTo` argument

`Array.sort` uses the `compareTo` method to know how to compare pairs of items from the array.

Your sort method assumes that it will only be called with instances of `Item`, and that's all `Array.sort` will pass along to `compareTo` assuming that your array only holds instances of `Item`.

You will get a runtime exception if `compareTo` is ever invoked with the item being compared to not being an instance of `Item`.

> I can't seem to understand `this.getNumber() < i.getNumber()` is doing...

It's comparing two instance of `Item` based on the value of `getNumber`, that is, the value of their `number` fields. It assumes that two instances of `Item` are equal if `Item.number` is the same for each instance, otherwise one is less than the other if its `Item.number` is less than the other's `Item.number`.

Comment: Thank you, so if i understand you correctly. items[0] = new Item(102, "Duct Tape"); <-this is the 1st instance so it return 0? items[1] = new Item(103, "Bailing wire"); <this is 2nd instance which is compare to the 1st instance?

Comment: @Eric Huang: Not quite. Depending on the exact implementation of `Arrays.sort`, `Item.compareTo` will be invoked on certain pairs of instances of `Item`. But considering you only have three items, we can easily list all possible pairs: `items[0].compareTo(items[0])` is `0` because `102 == 102`, `items[0].compareTo(items[1])` is `-1` because `102 < 103`, `items[0].compareTo(items[2])` is `1` because `102 > 103`, `items[1].compareTo(items[0])` is `1` because `103 < 102`, ... and so on. I encourage you to verify what I just wrote, and finish the list.

Comment: I sort of understand, I did what you told me and completed the rest of the list.  Basically any combination of `items[1].compareTo(items[x])` return 0, 1, 1. And `items[2].compareTo(items[x])` return 0, -1, -1.  So Item.compareTo doesn't start until Arrays.sort is being called. Arrays.sort invokes Item.compareTo so it will start comparing any pairs of instance.  That way it doesn't matter if I have 3,4 or 100 items... it will just sort.. Am i somewhat correct?

Answer (score 2):

The raw interface `Comparable` that you are using allows this object to be comparable to another `Object`.  It is then cast to `Item` to ensure that the `this` `Item` is only compared to another `Item`.

According to the [`Comparable` Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html),

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a
>   negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
>   than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Additionally, your `compareTo` will throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime if the `Object` isn't an `Item`.

It's better to use the generic form of the interface:

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
```

Then you can specify `Item` instead of `Object` to compare against:

```
@Override public int compareTo(Item i){
```

and you don't have to cast the `Object` to an `Item`.  When calling `compareTo`, the compiler will enforce that the object to compare to must be an `Item`.

Comment: I mean, the generics advice is correct in the future, but this code looks like it's from a book.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to override the default `compareTo()` method, which takes in a single `Object` as a parameter.  Thus, in your implementation, the parameter needs to be of type `Object`.  However, you assume that you will be passing in a `Item` object, so you can cast it accordingly.

So in the end, your `Item` object is treated like an `Object`, which is casted back to an `Item` in your `compareTo()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The Object being passed to your compareTo method is an Item object. The Arrays.sort() calls the Overrided method method when you have it implemented, the best implementation is to return the compareTo method for the primitive java types

```
 @Override 
 public int compareTo(Object o){
      return (this.getNumber().compareTo((Item)o.getNumber());
 }
```

(this requires you to have number as type Integer though)